Mirror shape key key giving error
I made a blender model and tried to make it blink using the shape key function.
I only did to only half of the face and the problem now is I get an error if I try to mirror shape key function and got a error
I then tried using (Mirror shape topology) the result was  and it looked like this
.
I've been looking at this problem for a few days and apparently it's because the head is not perfectly mirrored so I cut the head from the body so it's a separate mesh then deleted all shape keys and then cut half of the head off and then applied a mirror modifier then I did some new shape keys and attempted to mirror and what happened was it still didn't work both (normal mirror and topology) so pls help.
Thanks
:/
